# Split strings in Java using RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I want to split `String a = "1.48 kb";` in java.

```
String a = "1.48 kb";
String[] fileNameSplit = a.split(".\\s*[a-zA-Z]+");
System.out.println(fileNameSplit[0]);
```

Output is `1.4`
But I want output: `1.4 kb`

Comment: See https://ideone.com/SKwlzz, the output *is* `1.4`

Comment: Yes but I want 1.4 kb as output not 1.4

Comment: How come? Your regex clearly matches any char, then zero or more whitespces and then one  or more letters. Or did you think `.` matches a dot? Then you need to escape it, `a.split("\\.\\s*[a-zA-Z]+")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using this:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+.?\\d?)(\\d*)(\\s*[a-zA-Z]*)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("1.48 kb");
if (matcher.matches()) { // true
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // 1.4
   System.out.println(matcher.group(3)); //  kb

   String result = MessageFormat.format("{0}{1}", matcher.group(1), matcher.group(3));
   System.out.println(result); // 1.4 kb
}
```